# Webpack optimization for firefox addon

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

Im using webpack for bundling my chrome extension. I want to upload the extension to the store, but the files can't be larger than 4MB. So I tried to use webpack's code-splitting functionality to make the files smaller. Here is my optimization config:

[image: optimization]

With this Im able to upload it to the store, but the extension is broken. I can load it as an unpacked extension, but the extension is completely broken. Background page or pop are not loading. I don't get any errors in background script or in even popup:

[image: popup]

When I use `optimization.chunks: "async"` extension actually loads, but files are above 5MB and popup is throwing an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: illegal character U+20AC`.
[image: files]

Do you have any ideas, what could be happening?
If you have any questions feel free to ask!
Thank you

Comment: Try to analyze you bundle by `webpack-bundle-analyzer`
6MB for the bundle is a huge size
Do you use code optimization?
Share webpack config, package.json, `webpack-bundle-analyzer` report to help you

Comment: Sounds like you're embedding sourcemaps, in which case you need to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you use webpack code-splitting you have to link all the chunks in the HTML file with the script tag. For that I used `HtmlWebpackPlugin`. After that webpack will link all your chunks in the HMTL automatically.